# Spring Boot container won't connect to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

I want to connect my Spring Boot container with my database container. I can connect with a db app like db beaver.

Here is my setup:

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql


  reporter-service:
    image: openjdk:11-jdk
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
    container_name: reporter-service
    volumes:
      - ./reporter-service/build/libs:/usr/app
      - ./wait-for-it.sh:/usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh
    working_dir: /usr/app
    command: wait-for-it.sh mysql-db:3306 -t 240 -- java -jar reporter-service-*.jar


volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

Spring Boot **application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reporter-db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

**gradle.properties**

```
mariadbVersion=2.7.4
mysqlVersion=8.0.28
springBootVersion=2.6.3
mapstructVersion=1.4.2.Final
lombokVersion=1.18.20
liquibaseVersion=4.4.3
hibernate5Version=4.4.3
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "$springBootVersion"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.0.4'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.codesmith.reporterservice'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"


    implementation "org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:$mariadbVersion"
    implementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java:$mysqlVersion"

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.codesmith.reporterservice.ReporterServiceApplication'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += ['-Xlint:deprecation']
}

tasks.withType(Copy).all {
    duplicatesStrategy 'warn'
}

jar {
    enabled = false
}
```

**Exception**

```
reporter-service  | java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection refused (Connection refused)
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:197) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1394) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]    
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]      
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at com.codesmith.reporterservice.ReporterServiceApplication.main(ReporterServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[reporter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[reporter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[reporter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[reporter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
reporter-service  | Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection refused (Connection refused)
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:188) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createSocket(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:257) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:521) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1389) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     ... 57 common frames omitted
reporter-service  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
reporter-service  |     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createSocket(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:252) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     ... 59 common frames omitted
reporter-service  |
reporter-service  | 2022-02-12 22:23:24.425  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
reporter-service  |
reporter-service  | java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection refused (Connection refused)
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:197) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1394) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]    
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar!/:5.6.4.Final]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]      
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
reporter-service  |     at com.codesmith.reporterservice.ReporterServiceApplication.main(ReporterServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[reporter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[reporter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[reporter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
reporter-service  |     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[reporter-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
reporter-service  | Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection refused (Connection refused)
reporter-service  | 2022-02-12 22:23:25.256  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
```

At this point I'm stuck. The error does not tell me anything specific and it is difficult to find a solution here. I have tried to use other drivers so far but from my point of view everything is configured correctly, isn't it? The error occurs when I start the docker-compose up.

Comment: Trying to use maria db driver against a mysql db?

Comment: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` -- this is a specific socket-level error indicating that there's nothing listening on port 3306.  What do you see if you do `netstat -nat|grep LISTEN` in a console window?  Is there a listening socket on 3306?

Comment: ```TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         xxx      is listining``` 
i can access to the db with dbeaver with mariadb drivers but not with spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a network and environments so that containers can communicate,

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql-db:
    ...
    networks:
      - backend

  reporter-service:
    ...
    environment:
      spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://mysql-db:3306/reporter-db
      spring.datasource.driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
      spring.datasource.username: root
      spring.datasource.password:

    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  mysql-data:

networks:
  backend:
```

Note: `spring.datasource.url` must have MySQL docker service name as a host, which is, `mysql-db` in your case.